# Multiple Histograms in R

Tags: r, plot

For every command `hist()`, R keeps overwriting the previous histogram. How can I keep many histograms open without having to save?

**Note:** I am not asking for directions on how to plot histograms in the same panel.

Comment: Try using `X11()` before running `hist()`. `x11()` starts a graphics device each time it is run, this works if you are on windows or linux, if are using a Mac, then use `quartz()`.

Comment: will post it as an answer so that you can upvot it and accept it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `X11()` before running `hist()`. `x11()` starts a graphics device each time it is run, this works if you are on windows or linux, if are using a Mac, then use `quartz()`.

Find further details read the help files [`?x11()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/x11.html) and [`?quartz()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/quartz.html).

Comment: You could use `dev.new`, too. It should be platform independent.